# Python: Comparing two CSV lists

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare two csv files and search through them to find specific values. Example below.

---

FILE ONE

FirstName , LastName , Age

John    ,   Doe    ,  45

Jane    ,   Doe    ,  34

Robert  ,   Smite  ,  27

Bob     ,   White  ,  56

Cary    ,   Woods  ,  28

---

FILE TWO

FirstName

Robert

Jane

---

Script should use File Two's FirstName column to search in File One's FirstName column and return the age

Result
Robert, 27
Jane  , 34

My code only outputs Robert, 27 it does not continue to search for the second row of Jane. I tried using a While loop with no success. Any assistance will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Just FYI, I will be searching for 50+ items through a file with over 10k rows.

Code Below:

```
import csv

FileOne = open('/FileOne')
FileOneReader = csv.DictReader(FileOne)

FileTwo = open('/FileTwo')
FileTwoReader = csv.DictReader(FileTwo)


for row in FileTwoReader:
    for row2 in FileOneReader:
        if row['FirstName'].lower() in row2['FirstName'].lower():
            print 'Name:' + row['FirstName'] + ' Age: ' +   row2['Age'].lower()
```

Comment: The reason the second one is not printing is because you are reading the whole `csv.DictReader` object in the first iteration. One of your files is exhausted by the second iteration. You should save the data in lists and check that way.

Comment: The CSV file is suspect. See the [definition of CSV format] (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2). Just change this `if row['FirstName'].lower() in row2['FirstName'].lower():` to this `if row['FirstName'].lower() == row2['FirstName'].lower():` right after you clean up your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second one is not printing is because you are reading the whole `csv.DictReader` object (which is an `iterator`) in the first iteration. By the second iteration, one of your `iterators` is exhausted, so it won't return anything.

You should save the data in lists and do the checking that way. Here is a guide:

```
# Use with statements whenever you're working with more than one file
with open('full_names.csv') as fileone, open('first_names.csv') as filetwo:
    full_table = list(csv.DictReader(fileone))
    small_table = list(csv.DictReader(filetwo))
    for row1 in full_table:
        for row2 in small_table:
            if row2['FirstName'].lower() == row1['FirstName'].lower():
                print('Name: ' + row2['FirstName'] + ', Age: '+ row1['Age'].lower())
```

This should yield:

```
# Name: Jane, Age: 34
# Name: Robert, Age: 27
```

full_names.csv contains:

```
FirstName,LastName,Age
John,Doe,45
Jane,Doe,34
Robert,Smite,27
Bob,White,56
Cary,Woods,28
```

first_names.csv contains:

```
FirstName
Robert
Jane
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change the '==' in the if statement to 'in'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with pandas!

Import both csv files with pandas, merge the second csv with the first, and then select the desired variable(s).

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'LastA', 30], ['B', 'LastB', 20], ['C', 'LastB', 10]],
                    columns=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A'], ['B']],
                   columns=['FirstName'])

df2.merge(df1, on='FirstName')[['FirstName', 'Age']]

## -- End pasted text --
Out[7]:
  FirstName  Age
0         A   30
1         B   20
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will learn more about pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Mayeb something like this?

```
import csv

FileOne = open('/FileOne')
FileOneReader = csv.DictReader(FileOne)

FileTwo = open('/FileTwo')
FileTwoReader = csv.DictReader(FileTwo)

names_to_check = []

for row in FileTwoReader:
    names_to_check.append(row['FirstName'].lower())

for row in FileOneReader:
    if row['FirstName'].lower() in names_to_check:
        print "Name: {} Age: {}".format(row['FirstName'], row['Age'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!